# How to incrementally rename files after processing in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, pdf, script, tesseract-ocr

I have a set of files that need processing, so I tend to do this programmatically in `bash` in mac and linux. Since I like to keep the originals in case something gets screwed, I want the files to come out renumbered incrementally, but I don't know the proper `bash` construction to accomplish this.

Here's an example. I have a set of .pdf files:

```
bulletinlois00.pdf
bulletinlois01.pdf
bulletinlois02.pdf
...
bulletinlois33.pdf
```

The pdfs have not yet been OCRed, and so I want to iterate through them with `tesseract` or `ocrmypdf` but instead of outputting them like `bulletinlois01.pdf` they would be `01.pdf`. Here is another example using the same file set. I want to iterate through files doing `pdftotext`, but instead of having `bulletinlois01.pdf` go to `bulletinlois01.txt` I want it to be `01.txt`

I could do a `cp`+`mv` process, or `grep` to replace the unwanted parts of the names, but this seems overkill and gets me confused about whether I should be using `wait` or a `&&` construction.

Is there a simple way to script this using `bash`, and **could you please explain what exactly the construction is doing** so that I can learn how to adapt it to other, more complex processing I need to do? For instance, maybe I could use the construction to output the names using

```
`date "+%H.%M.%S"`
```

Here's the rudimentary script:

```
for f in *.pdf ; do
    tesseract -l fra "$f" "$f"_done.pdf
done
```

Comment: You should post your actual Bash script instead of explaining what it does. Please edit your question to add it.

Comment: @JakeGould if it wasn't clear enough, I do not know how to do this

Comment: Are the new filenames (e.g. `01.pdf`) named that way because the incoming filename has `01` in it, or because it's (e.g.) the first file being processed?  If 01.pdf already exists, what should happen?  It's confusing that your example code indicates a new filename of "_done" instead of a sequence number.

Comment: good point. ideally, it would be 01.pdf because the incoming file has 01 in it, which would let me compare the output quality to the original. I added the _done so the next command would be something like `mv "$f"_done.pdf ...` to something like 01.pdf, but I realized that sort of `mv` construction would simply write over each file. I suspect I need some sort of array expansion, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more control over the resulting filenames by stripping prefix and suffix from the matched filenames.

This is one possible way to achieve that:

```bsh
for matched_filename in bulletinlois*.pdf ; do

    # strip "bulletinlois" prefix from the filename
    tmp=${matched_filename#bulletinlois}

    # then strip ".pdf" suffix
    number=${tmp%\.pdf}

    tesseract -l fra "$matched_filename" "$number"_done.pdf
done
```

Stripping in this example is done using bash [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

To find out more about shell parameter expansion visit [this blog post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) or [the official bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).